# SWIG, Python and Pointers

Tags: python, swig

I'm trying to wrap a C API (static library) from which the source is not available. One of the first tasks in using the API is to set up the environment structure.

```
env_t * my_env = NULL;
result = env_setup(&my_env);
```

with declaration

```
error_code env_setup(env_t ** env);
```

Is it even possible to manufacture pointers of this type (env_t **) in SWIG, considering that the layout of the env structure is hidden?

Comment: This is a good question, however (a) please improve the formatting, and (b) please go back to your previous questions and accept the answers so as to encourage people to answer this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to do some manipulation with typemaps.

```
%typemap(in) env_t ** (env_t *temp) %{
    temp = env_alloc();
    PyObject *iter = PyObject_GetIter($input);
    for (PyObject *item; (item = PyIter_Next(it));) {
        PyObject *key = PyObject_Str(item);
        PyObject *val = PyObject_GetItem($input, key);
        env_set(temp, PyString_AsString(key), PyString_AsString(val), ENV_OVERRIDE);
        Py_DECREF(val);
        Py_DECREF(key);
        Py_DECREF(item);
    }
    Py_DECREF(iter);
    $1 = &temp;
%}
%typemap(argout) env_t** %{
    PyObject *o = PyDict_New();
    for (char **val = env_array(*$1); *val; val++) {
        char *eq = strchr(*val, '=');
        *eq = '\0';
        PyMapping_SetItemString(o, *val, eq + 1);
    }
    env_free(*$1);
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, o);
%}
```

Totally untested and lacking in error handling, but the intent here is to transform a `dict` into an `env_t **` when calling from Python to C, and from `env_t **` to `dict` when returning from C to Python.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was able to do it in Cython in < 20 lines.  If anyone reads this, I suggest to use Cython instead of SWIG if you only need Python support.